# Weekly activity summary help? SWIFTUI

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm tryin' to obtain a list of activities ("dd/mm/YY: goal achieved/missed goal") which has to be setted every week. The problem is that I obtain a list of activities with the same date and the same result of the previous one. For example:

```
28/02/2022: goal achieved
28/02/2022: goal achieved
28/02/2022: goal achieved
```

and the next day:

```
01/03/2022: missed goal
01/03/2022: missed goal
01/03/2022: missed goal
01/03/2022: missed goal
```

**I want to obtain, instead, a list like:**

```
28/02/2022: goal achieved
01/03/2022: missed goal
02/03/2022: goal achieved...
```

These are useful structs:

```
struct Persistent {
 @AppStorage("goalAchieved") static var goalAchieved : Bool = false
 @AppStorage("activityList") static var activityList : [String] = []
}

struct obj {
static var currentDate = Date()
static var stringDate = ""
static var activity = Activity(date:Persistent.lastUpdatedDate)
}
```

This is the ActivityListView:

```
import SwiftUI

func activitystring(activity:Activity) -> String{
var output = ""
output = "\(activity.date): \(activity.reachedobj(goalAchieved: Persistent.goalAchieved))"
return output

}

struct Activity: Identifiable{

let id = UUID()
let date: String

func reachedobj(goalAchieved: Bool) -> String {
     var output = ""
    if Persistent.goalAchieved == false { output = "Missed goal" }
    if Persistent.goalAchieved == true { output = "Goal Achieved!"}
     
     return output
     
 }

 }

struct ActivityRow: View{

var activity: Activity


var body: some View{
    Text(activitystring(activity: activity))
    Divider()
}
}



struct ActivityListView: View {


var body: some View {
    
    ScrollView{
        
        Text("Week summary").font(.system(size: 15)).foregroundColor(Color.green)
        
        Text("")
        
    ForEach(Persistent.activityList, id: \.self) { activity in 
        
        let activity = Activity(date: Persistent.lastUpdatedDate)
        ActivityRow(activity: activity)
        
        }
    
    }
}

}
```

Finally this is the useful code in the ApplicationApp file (main) where I update activity list:

```
MenuView().onAppear(){
                    
       if Persistent.activityList.count>7{
          Persistent.activityList.removeAll()
       }
                    
      obj.currentDate = Date()
      let formatter = DateFormatter()
      formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/YY"
      obj.stringDate = formatter.string(from:obj.currentDate)

      if Persistent.lastUpdatedDate != obj.stringDate{

      Persistent.goalAchieved = false
      let activity = Activity(date: Persistent.lastUpdatedDate)
      Persistent.activityList.append(activitystring(activity: activity))
      Persistent.lastUpdatedDate = obj.stringDate

      }                  
 }
```

What's wrong on this?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Persistent` object you have an array of many activities, called `activitylist` , but one single boolean that tells if the goal is achieved - `goalachieved` indeed.

Your view is iterating through the array of `Persistent.activitylist`, so you will have many lines for one single result - achieved or not achieved. You might actually want to iterate over an array of `Persistent` objects - meaning that somewhere you should probably store `[Persistent]` in some variable. In this way, you will see one line only for each result.

If I also may suggest: use the conventions for naming variables, Swift uses "camelCaseConventionForVariables", easier to read than "thewholevariableislowercase"

**Edit:**

Let me try to change a little bit your code (I would personally change it more radically, but that's not the scope of the answer).

Instead of having only one `goalAchieved` for all elements on the array `activityList`, make it a dictionary:

```
struct Persistent {

 // Drop this variable
 // @AppStorage("goalAchieved") static var goalAchieved : Bool = false

 // Make this a dictionary, the date will be the key and the goalAchieved will be the value
 @AppStorage("activityList") static var activityList : [String: Bool] = [:]
}
```

Add values to the dictionary (@meomeomeo is right, you don't need `obj`):

```
MenuView().onAppear() {
                    
       if Persistent.activityList.count > 7 {
          Persistent.activityList.removeAll()
       }
                    
      let currentDate = Date()
      let formatter = DateFormatter()
      formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/YY"
      let stringDate = formatter.string(from: currentDate)

      if Persistent.lastUpdatedDate != stringDate {

      
          let activity = Activity(date: Persistent.lastUpdatedDate)
          Persistent.activityList[activitystring(activity: activity))] = false   // Will create something like ["01/03/2022": false]
          Persistent.lastUpdatedDate = stringDate

      }                  
 }
```

Iterate on the dictionary in your ForEach; for more info: [read here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html).

Comment: I didn't insert here, but there's a code where goalAchieved changes based on the activity of the user and the func **reachedobj** gives me the correct result. The problem is that each day the row is added but then the previous ones become like the new row. Sorry for my English (I'm italian) but I didn't understand what I have to do with Persistent.activitylist

Comment: Your `Persistent` object has an array of strings called `activityList` and one value for `goalAchieved`. So, all elements in `activityList` have the same value for `goalAchieved`. When you iterate using `ForEach(Persistent.activityList...`, all items in the list will return the exact same value of `goalAchieved`. Mo' cambio un po' la risposta e vedrai (i.e., now I'll edit the answer with an example).

Comment: Faccio prima a scriverti in italiano allora hahaha

Comment: Quando provo a inizializzare @AppStorage("activityList") static var activityList : [String: Bool] = [:] mi da questo errore: ** No exact matches in call to initializer **

Comment: Try `@AppStorage("activityList") static var activityList = [String: Bool]() `. Let's use English, to keep this forum open to everyone...

Comment: Tried, same error.. it's strange , I tried all possible ways to initialize It. I also tried include some libraries like Collections but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `obj.activity` in your `ForEach` and `ActivityRow`, that's why it repeats that same static property all over the place.

You better just drop your `struct obj` and try again without it

Comment: I dropped it but still there's the problem :(

Comment: Because it is just one of many problems you have in your code, it seem like you don't really know what your code doing. Maybe you should practice something smaller, easier before writing bunch of codes that you don't really understand.

Comment: Yes I'm very new in Xcode and in Swift, I followed a Swift course at the university which lasted only one month and now I have to complete an internship application for watchOS with the little knowledge I have and completely alone.. this is the only problem I have to fix, I hope that with your helps I will be able to make it work :)

Comment: I don't think me or anyone on SO should help you with that, there are no short cut in a developer way. Keep asking other to do your homework only get you more down vote here. Good luck with your internship anyway.